# Assigning multiple values to keys?

Tags: python-3.x

I need help assigning multiple values to keys. I know there is other questions like this one, however I don't really get their examples.

Here's my code, I want to add a damage value to the sword keys.

```
normalswords={
"TRAINING SWORD":"A sword meant for training, no element, 10 damage"}
```

Please help!

Comment: Assign a key to a list as the value?

Comment: What do you not understand about the other questions and their examples?

Comment: @TheGamerCow, As suggested, why don't you make a list of the values you want to include for the key? `normalswords={"TRAINING SWORD":["A sword meant for training", "no element", "10 damage"]}`, then `normalswords['TRAINING SWORD'][2]` returns `'10 damage'`. Is that what you are asking for?

Comment: Yeah actually except I want the "10 damage" to be an integer. Thank you

Comment: Sure, glad to try to help. So try `normalswords={"TRAINING SWORD":["A sword meant for training", "no element", 10]}`, then `normalswords['TRAINING SWORD'][2]` will return `10`. You can confirm it's an integer like this: `type(normalswords['TRAINING SWORD'][2])` returns -> `<type 'int'>`